# Стандартные модули Kohana Framework, такие как CodeBench, UnitTest, Minion?

Tags: юнит-тесты, kohana

Кто сталкивался с работой с этими модулями, можете объяснить их предназначение. Либо же привести пару примеров работы с любым из них. В доках фреймворка написано по английски, поэтому остаются пробелы в понимании. Например тот же `Minion`, это работа с командной строкой, но как его на практике применить я не пойму, `bat` что ли в корне сайта создать и его запускать через класс? То же самое с `Codebench`, я так понял это вывод статистики, т.с. `профилирование` по работе сайта, пример взял из хабра:

```
public function after()
{
    $this->request->response.=View::factory('profiler/stats');
}
```

По всей логики вещей это нужно вставить в любой контроллер, предварительно включив `Kohana::$profiling=TRUE`. Я это сделал, но толку никакого, контроллер вообще не срабатывает, выводится пустая страница. А так же: `Unittest`, что это?

Answer (score 1):

> Я это сделал, но толку никакого, контроллер вообще не срабатывает, выводится пустая страница.

Вероятнее всего у вас ошибка в коде, вывод которой подавляется настройками PHP, поэтому скрипт завершается вообще без вывода. Проверьте логи сервера/php/коханы.

> А так же: Unittest, что это?

Это модуль для т.н. модульного тестирования (unit testing), который, судя по всему, служить простой оберткой для phpunit. Модульное тестирование  предлагает возможность задать входные и ожидаемые выходные данные для тех или иных модулей, и проверить таким образом верность работы всех написанных функций. Чем более хитрые данные скармливаются модульному тестированию, тем меньше вероятность, что что-то полетит уже в стадии продакшена.

Вообще, все есть в [документации](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/unittest/testing)

Comment: `$ phpunit --bootstrap=modules/unittest/bootstrap.php modules/unittest/tests.php` у меня Windows.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу кодбенча и логов, там все чисто.

Comment: @Smash

> у меня Windows.

phpunit написан на php, ему без разницы

> Кстати, по поводу кодбенча и логов, там все чисто.

Если запихнуть вот такое в самое начало входного скрипта, что-нибудь изменится?

    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: нету никаких ошибок, чистый лист.

Comment: @Smash, в логах есть что-нибудь подозрительное? Если оставить after пустым, будет какой-нибудь вывод?

Comment: @Fike, да, оставил пустым:

 // for the CodeBench Module Test
 public function after()
 {
  // $this->request->response.=View::factory('profiler/stats');
 }

Итог чистая страница. В логах нормально все, возможно этот метод как-то не так приспособлен или я его не так применяю? п.с. применяю в базовом контроллере.

Comment: @Smash, похоже, проблема не в after, а в основном методе-действии. В родительском контроллере (по крайней мере, в последней версии коханы) он вообще пустой (т.е. наличие/отсутствие не должно играть никакой роли). Можно попробовать сделать die('tralala') чтобы увидеть, доходит до него вообще дело, или нет, и через какой-нибудь var\_dump посмотреть, что находится в этот момент в response.

Answer (score 1):

Модуль Minion http://brotkin.ru/2012/03/28/minion-module/